# Compile Typescript without DOM declarations

Tags: typescript

I would like to compile TypeScript without including the DOM declarations. The environment I'm working with doesn't have any DOM, only pure ES6 features. For example I want to have my own Window class, but right now it conflicts with the Window class coming from DOM lib file. I only want to include ES6 declarations when compiling, can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript 2 introduced a new compiler options called `lib`.
Using that option you can now:

> specify a list of built-in API declaration groups that you can chose
>   to include in your project

I haven't had the change to use it, but [according to the docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-including-built-in-type-declarations-with---lib):

> you can exclude declarations you do not want to include in your
>   project, e.g. DOM if you are working on a node project using --lib
>   es5,es6.

So should be something like:

```
tsc --lib es5,es6
```

Or:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es5", "es6"]
}
```